# Java : Using addAll method on Custom list

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to use the addAll() method on custom list. 
I have the following Java code;

```
PaginatedResponse<CustomType> paginatedResponse = new PaginatedResponse<CustomType>();
List<PaginatedResponse<CustomType>> paginatedResponseList = new ArrayList<PaginatedResponse<CustomType>>();
paginatedResponseList.addAll(methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType);
```

However I am getting an error. no suitable method found for addAll()

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `addAll()` takes a collection you just need `add()`

Comment: Is methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType a collection type? Share that code.

Comment: Yeah, if `methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType` returns a `PaginatedResponse<CustomType>`, and not a collection of them, you probably want to write something like `paginatedResponseList.add(methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType());` - don't forget the parentheses to call the method, and use `add`, not `addAll`.

Comment: What is the type of methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType. If addAll method is called, then methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType should be a type of collection type, like List<PaginatedResponse<CustomType>> . Please check it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **addAll** method is called, then in your code example, methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType should be a type of collection type, like List< PaginatedResponse< CustomType > > .

If methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType  is a type of PaginatedResponse< CustomType >, then you need to use **add** rather than addAll.

If methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType  is a type of CustomType, then the element in list does not match with methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType that you would like to add.

Check if the type is macthing first.

Comment: Thx a lot...methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType is returning PaginatedResponse<CustomType >

Comment: So , I'll use paginatedResponseList.add(methodReturningPaginatedResponseOfCustomType())

Comment: In PaginatedResponse, I have a List<records> , which is returned using  getRecords()

Comment: How do I access the same using paginatedResponseList ?

Comment: I mean I want to do ; paginatedResponseList. SOMETHING . getRecords() ...So what will be that SOMETHING  ?

Comment: It is OK. I am glad to have helped you.
:)

Comment: Could you please help me on the last part as well....retrieving the List<records> from PaginatedResponse using paginatedResponseList

Comment: Someting like:    for(PaginatedResponse<CustomType> paginatedResponse :paginatedResponseList ) { List<Records> recordsList = paginatedResponse.getRecords(); //Then you can do something here }

Comment: If you have any problem, just let me know. :)